# Show buttons on a div element onhovering as an overlay

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am having a div element which displays a chart.my aim is to show a blurred overlay on hovering the chart and show a set of butttons.

my div

```
<div className='col-lg-3 card-container3'>
                                        <div className="card-content2">
                                             <BarCharts chartLabel='daily' handleZoom={handleZoom} data={data}  options={data.options?data.options:options_flights}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

the related css

```
  .card-container3 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    @include myTheme.theme-aware('border-color', 'cardBorderColor');
    @include myTheme.theme-aware('background', 'cardContentColor-bg');
    width: calc((100% - 5%) / 3);
    min-height: 230px;
    margin: 0 .5rem 1.5rem 0;
    @extend .white;
    padding: 0px 25px 2px 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }



   .card-content2 {
      display: grid;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-content: center;
      min-height: 200px;

      .card-icon-block {
        padding: 0 0 20px 0;

        img {
          /* height: 47px;width: 47px; */
          height: calc(0.9rem + 2vw);
          width: calc(0.9rem + 2vw);
        }
      }
```

i have tried

```
.card-content2:hover{
background-color:'#6f42c1';
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

i was able to get the hover effects by applying this any suggestions in adding buttons on hover in the element?

my UI should be looking like this in a before after perspective

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser inspector, try to find a selector for these buttons, and use this selector to show the buttons on hover.

For example, if the buttons have a class called `button-class`.

```
.card-content2:hover {
  background-color:'#6f42c1';
  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  .button-class {
    display: inline;   // if `display: none`
    visibility: visible;  // if `visibility: hidden`
    opacity: 1;  // if `opacity: 0`
  }
}
```